# Sort elements in rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html

I have the number 4, the number of columns.

Furthermore I have an unordered list containing X number of elements

```
<ul>
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 1</li>
  etc.
</ul>
```

I would like the following output:

```
<ul>
  <li data-row="1" data-column="1">element 1</li>
  <li data-row="1" data-column="2">element 1</li>
  <li data-row="1" data-column="3">element 1</li>
  <li data-row="1" data-column="4">element 1</li>
  <li data-row="2" data-column="1">element 1</li>
  <li data-row="2" data-column="2">element 1</li>
  <li data-row="2" data-column="3">element 1</li>
  etc.
</ul>
```

How do I do this in a clever way?

Comment: What do you mean by `I have the number 4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division and modulo:

```
lis = yourULElement.getElementsByTagName('li') // the <li> elements
limit = 4 // your number

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i ++) {
    lis[i].setAttribute('data-row', Math.floor(i / limit) + 1)
    lis[i].setAttribute('data-column', i % limit + 1)
}
```

**[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYPKb/1/).**

[image]

Explanation:

```
      | i / 4,            |
Index | Math.floor(i / 4) | i % 4
------+-------------------+-------
0     | 0, 0              | 0
1     | 0.25, 0           | 1
2     | 0.5, 0            | 2
3     | 0.75, 0           | 3
4     | 1, 1              | 0
5     | 1.25, 1           | 1
6     | 1.5, 1            | 2
7     | 1.75, 1           | 3
```

Comment: This is awesome. Its the right approach, but the numbers are not entirely right. The rows are 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,etc and the columns are 1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0

Comment: @tolborg No they're not. Did you try the fiddle?

Comment: @Doorknow sorry didnt see you changed the code. This is awesome!